# Replacing fax lines with online service

Tags: email, printing, fax

I know there are various online fax companies but I want to know how I can have them operate like a traditional fax.  We have around 5 different fax numbers currently at different locations.  I don't want to have to manage user accounts on the various online fax services.  Is there a way that I can retrieve a fax from an online service and have it printed to a network printer?  For sending faxes I'd like the users to go to our Xerox all in one devices and do a scan to email like 2125551212@sendmyfax.com in order to send them.

My main goal is to make the switch nearly seamless to the users.  Our POTS lines have been problematic as of late and Verizon doesn't treat them with any urgency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automatic email manager seems like the solution
http://www.automatic-email-manager.com/Default.aspx

You can configure your online fax service to send to an email(s) for incoming faxes and the program will print or save them for you automatically.  I haven't tried it yet but it looks pretty promising.

Answer (score 0):

I am using online fax from Popfax: http://www.popfax.com and you can receive faxes directly on your email, desktop, and mobile devise, and you can print them straight away to your network printer. 
You can try the service for free and see how it works.

Comment: Does the service work as a single user, and does it automatically print, or do you need to view the FAX on a client (phone, laptop) first?